# Select one cell and by clicking a button change value of a different cell

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to insert a button into my google spreadsheet, that, when clicked, copies the content of the selected cell to another cell. Is there any way to do this?

I tried googling for a solution myself, but I'm overwhelmed by all sorts of different scripts/macros/addons that are available.

Would be amazing if you could help me out on this one.

Comment: Record a macro?

Answer (score 2):

you will need a script for this purpose like:

```
function moveValuesOnly1() { 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
 var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
 source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet2!B1"), {contentsOnly: true}); }
```

which copies selected cell from selected sheet into **B1** cell of **Sheet2**

and then just go **Insert** > **Drawings** and create a button. when done link the script with button and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear enough though, when I said "selected" cell. I wanted to select any cell in my sheet by clicking on it and then click the button to copy the contend of the selected cell to another cell.

Comment: Alright, thats too bad. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @player0 See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSelection())